# Cannot read property 'boundingSphere' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, three.js

I'm displaying points using react-three-renderer in a 3D graph and getting the issue "Cannot read property 'boundingSphere' of undefined". Below is my code. Please help how I can solve this issue.

```
{
  points &&
    points.map(p => ( <
      points key = {
        p.clusterId
      }
      position = {
        new THREE.Vector3(p.xdim, p.ydim, p.zdim)
      } >
      <
      pointsMaterial color = {
        '#6ddff2'
      }
      /> <
      /points>
    ))
}
```

Comment: Your error is telling you exactly what's happening. It's trying to access the `boundingSphere` property of an object which doesn't exist (is `undefined`). Look at the file/line number associated with the error to find out where it's happening (the code you shared has no references to `boundingSphere`). If you still can't see the problem, please post the actual related code and the full error, and we'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the reply. I forgot to add the geometry to the point for which this error is thrown by threejs.